# HTML5/JavaScript audio playlist

Tags: javascript, html, audio, playlist

I have found a nice tutorial on how to build a playlist using HTML5 and JavaScript in blog post *[HTML5 Audio and Video and how to make a playlist](http://blog.lastrose.com/html5-audio-video-playlist/)*. I followed the instructions, but I did not get the correct outcome.

This code SHOULD play all three audio files in order and stop when the last song has ended, but it what it actually does is autoplay the first file then stops when the first file is completed. What did I do wrong?

```
<html>
    <body>
        <ul id="playlist">
            <li class="active">
                <a href="http://www.codenamejupiterx.com/song/soundtest.mp3">
                   soundtest
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="http://www.codenamejupiterx.com/song/soundtest2.mp3">
                    soundtest2
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="http://www.codenamejupiterx.com/song/soundtest3.mp3">
                    soundtest3
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <script>
            var audio;
            var playlist;
            var tracks;
            var current;

            init();
            function init(){
                current = 0;
                audio = $('#audio');
                playlist = $('#playlist');
                tracks = playlist.find('li a');
                len = tracks.length - 1;
                audio[0].volume = .10;
                audio[0].play();
                playlist.find('a').click(function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    link = $(this);
                    current = link.parent().index();
                    run(link, audio[0]);
                });
                audio[0].addEventListener('ended',function(e){
                    current++;
                    if(current == len){
                        current = 0;
                        link = playlist.find('a')[0];
                    }
                    else{
                        link = playlist.find('a')[current];
                    }
                    run($(link),audio[0]);
                });
            }

            function run(link, player){
                player.src = link.attr('href');
                par = link.parent();
                par.addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
                audio[0].load();
                audio[0].play();
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1)** JavaScript code is using jQuery (those `$(...)` statements), so it must be imported:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
  </head>
<body>
...
```

**2)** The `audio` HTML element (the real "player") is missed:

```
<body>
  <audio id="audio" preload="auto" tabindex="0" controls="" >
    <source src="http://www.codenamejupiterx.com/song/soundtest.mp3">
  </audio>
...
```

**3)** The code play only TWO songs. To play THREE:

```
...
len = tracks.length; //"-1" removed
...
```

**4)** The code play again and again the three songs. To stop it:

```
audio[0].addEventListener('ended',function(e){
    current++;
    if(current < len){
      link = playlist.find('a')[current];   
      run($(link),audio[0]);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Juan!!!! But one thing I removed the -1 from the len=track.length line but it still only plays two tracks....any sugesgtions?

Comment: it was my browser safari 5 when i upgraded to safari 6 it worked like a charm.  Thanks Juan!!!!

Answer (score -3):

Using jQuery I do have achieved this by using the following control.

Add the audio Control tag with following parameters:

```
<audio id="audio1" controls="controls" autoplay="autoplay">    </audio>
```

And in JavaScript:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var supportsAudio = !!document.createElement('audio').canPlayType;
    if (supportsAudio) {

        url = URL.baseUrl + Books + authors + "/" + subject + "/data.json";
        $.getJSON(url, function(data){
            console.log("ddd"+JSON.stringify(data));

            var index = 0,
            trackCount = data.URL.length,
                npAction = $('#npAction'),
                npTitle = $('#npTitle'),
                audioid = $('#audio1').bind('play', function() {
                }).bind('ended', function() {

                if((index + 1) < trackCount) {
                    index++;
                    loadTrack(index);
                    audioid.play();
                }
                else {
                    audioid.pause();
                    index = 0;
                    loadTrack(index);
                }
            }).get(0),
                loadTrack = function(id) {
                    index = id;
                    audioid.src = data.URL[index].ayah;
                };
            loadTrack(index);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: This is an [exact duplicate of this other answer of yours](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18035392/control-multiple-html5-audio-tracks-using-a-single-controller/19537548#19537548).

Comment: Your script is full of references to variables that aren't defined in this scope (`Books`, `authors`, `subject`) as well as assumptions about the DOM (`#npAction`, `#npTitle`).  This needs a lot more explanation if it's going to be helpful to others.