# Control multiple html5 audio tracks using a single controller

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio, jquery

I am trying to implement a very minimal audio player for a web site.

The interface is rather simple. It has a play/pause button, and a mute/unmute button.

The problem I have is implementing multiple instances of the same player for different tracks.

The javascript for the player is:

```
jQuery(function() {
    var myAudio = document.getElementById("myAudio");
    var btnPlayPause = document.getElementById("btnPlayPause");
    var btnMute = document.getElementById("btnMute");

    btnPlayPause.addEventListener("click", function() {
        if (myAudio.paused || myAudio.ended) {
            myAudio.play();
            btnPlayPause.innerHTML = "<span aria-hidden=\"true\" data-icon=\"&#xe003;\"></span><span class=\"screen-reader-text\">Play</span>";
        }
        else {
            myAudio.pause();
            btnPlayPause.innerHTML = "<span aria-hidden=\"true\" data-icon=\"&#xe002;\"></span><span class=\"screen-reader-text\">Pause</span>";
        }
    });

    btnMute.addEventListener("click", function() {
        if (myAudio.muted) {
            myAudio.muted = false;
            btnMute.innerHTML = "<span aria-hidden=\"true\" data-icon=\"&#xe001;\"></span><span class=\"screen-reader-text\">Mute</span>";
        }
        else {
            myAudio.muted = true;
            btnMute.innerHTML = "<span aria-hidden=\"true\" data-icon=\"&#xe000;\"></span><span class=\"screen-reader-text\">Unmute</span>";
        }
    });
});
```

This works fine for a single track. But if I have multiple tracks on the same page, this becomes a problem.

I am guessing that I need some modification to the syntax where I define the myAudio variable:

`var myAudio = document.getElementById("myAudio");`

However, I am not sure how to change that so the same script can control multiple audio tracks.

If possible, I also would like to be able to ensure that if the user clicks the play button on a different track, the track that is currently playing "stops" or is "paused" and the new track starts (so 2 tracks are not playing on top of each other).

Comment: Is there a question in there?

Comment: Yes, how can I modify the script so that the same script can control several different tracks. Right now. If I click play on one track, ALL the tracks play at once.

Comment: That is good if I want to have a playlist. In this case, there is not a playlist, but each track will have a play button next to it. I need to have the play button play the associated track, and only that track. If you click on the play button next to another track, then the currently playing track will pause and the newly clicked on track will play. But that solution will be useful for a 2nd player that is site-wide on the site, so that still is very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is jQuery based solution. To make HTML5 audio work also in IE8/7 use some additional [flash fallback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11681856/html5-audio-tag-flash-fall-back).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title> - jsFiddle demo</title>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.js'></script>
  <style type='text/css'>
.mp3Player {
    padding:8px;
    margin:8px;
    background-color:#ddf;
}
  </style>

<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 

jQuery(function (){
    var myAudio = document.getElementById("myAudio");
    var current = null;
    var playingString = "<span aria-hidden=\"true\" data-icon=\"&#xe002;\"></span><span class=\"screen-reader-text\">Pause</span>";
    var pausedString = "<span aria-hidden=\"true\" data-icon=\"&#xe003;\"></span><span class=\"screen-reader-text\">Play</span>";
    $(document.body).on('click', '.btnPlayPause',function(e){
        var target = this;
        //console.log(target, current); //return;
        if (current == target) {
            target.innerHTML = pausedString;
            target.parentNode.setAttribute('data-pos', myAudio.currentTime); //start from paused
            myAudio.pause();
            current = null;
        } else { // current!=target
            if (current != null) {
                current.innerHTML = pausedString;
                current.parentNode.setAttribute('data-pos', '0'); //reset position
                target.parentNode.setAttribute('data-pos', myAudio.currentTime); //start from paused
            }
            current = target;
            target.innerHTML = playingString;
            if(myAudio.canPlayType && myAudio.canPlayType("audio/mpeg") != "") { // MP3
                myAudio.src = target.parentNode.getAttribute('data-src');
            } else if(myAudio.canPlayType && myAudio.canPlayType("audio/ogg") != "") {  // OGG
                myAudio.src = target.parentNode.getAttribute('data-src2');
            } else {
                return; // no audio support
            }
            myAudio.play();
            myAudio.onloadeddata = function () {
                myAudio.currentTime = parseFloat(target.parentNode.getAttribute('data-pos'));
            };
        }
    });
    $(document.body).on('click', '.btnMute',function(e){
        myAudio.muted = !myAudio.muted;
        $('.btnMute').each(function(){
            if (myAudio.muted) {
                this.innerHTML = "<span aria-hidden=\"true\" data-icon=\"&#xe001;\"></span><span class=\"screen-reader-text\">Muted</span>";
            } else {
                this.innerHTML = "<span aria-hidden=\"true\" data-icon=\"&#xe000;\"></span><span class=\"screen-reader-text\">Audible</span>";
            }
        });
    });
});

//]]>  
</script>
</head>
<body>

<audio id="myAudio"></audio>

<div class="mp3Player" data-src="a.mp3" data-src2="a.ogg" data-pos="0">
    <button class="btnPlayPause button">►||</button>
    <button class="btnMute button">MUTE</button>
    <span class="infoLabel">Audio #1</span>
</div>

<div class="mp3Player" data-src="b.mp3" data-src2="b.ogg" data-pos="0">
    <button class="btnPlayPause button">►||</button>
    <button class="btnMute button">MUTE</button>
    <span class="infoLabel">Audio #2</span>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

jQuery [code](http://jsfiddle.net/F35Fw/12/) + [result page](http://jsfiddle.net/F35Fw/12/show/).

javascript [code](http://jsfiddle.net/F35Fw/8/) + [result page](http://jsfiddle.net/F35Fw/8/show/).

Both scripts need additional existing .mp3 files to play the sound

Comment: Stano, that looks great, two quick questions. Can you help me change that to a noconflict jQuery script, and also, can you help me modify the play/pause button's style to use `<span aria-hidden=\"true\" data-icon=\"&#xe003;\"></span><span class=\"screen-reader-text\">Play</span>` for play and `<span aria-hidden=\"true\" data-icon=\"&#xe002;\"></span><span class=\"screen-reader-text\">Pause</span>` for pause. So, the same button will play/pause but will have different icons for Play/Pause depending on the state. These are custom play and pause icons. In this player, I won't need a mute button.

Comment: Also, I see an onload event. None of the tracks should play onload, but onclick only.

Comment: Well, added jQuery alternative with all the IE incompatible code updated http://jsfiddle.net/F35Fw/10/

Comment: I am assuming to make it jQuery noconflict, I just replace the `$` with `jQuery` and that's that?

Comment: I also have another question. This only plays .mp3 files. Ideally, it should play .mp3 or .ogg, depending on browser capability, and only load the version of the audio file the browser can play (not both). How could I put a test to determine capability then source the appropriate audio format, assuming the file name is the same, and only the file extension changes. So, the file name could be `mozbeemora_beethoven1_cadenza_1` and it would get either a `.mp3` or a `.ogg` depending on the browser.

Comment: I am ready to accept your answer, just need to make the jQuery noconflict and also get the audio format test in there. Then I'm good to go and will happily accept your answer.

Comment: Hi Stano, not sure how to implement that test. I understand the principle, but completely lost on how to implement it. Can you help me?  I know that the tests are for mp3 `"audio/mpeg"` with codecs `mpeg` and for `"audio/ogg"` with codecs `"vorbis"`

Comment: Also, I know you don't **need** your answer to be accepted, but I always accept answers that solve my issues.

Comment: Thanks alisamii, updated the answer, please try this code instead http://jsfiddle.net/F35Fw/12/ Hope it helps ;-)

Comment: Is there a way to modify this `<div class="mp3Player" data-src="a.mp3" data-src2="a.ogg" data-pos="0">` such that I can have `data-src=a.ext` where the `ext` is replaced with the supported ext. What I mean is, that I can reference the file name itself, but not the extension, and let the javascript determine the extension and append it to the file name. This would allow me to eliminate `data-src2` and would be cleaner. It would also allow me to add tests for other audio formats and potentially embed others, based on browser capability, without adding multiple `data-src` attributes.

Comment: Good idea, imo it should be no problem. Please try this: http://jsfiddle.net/F35Fw/13/

Comment: Hey, are you available for a quick chat? I'm getting a conflict with the script and would appreciate your help.

Comment: are you on chat.stackoverflow.com? would make it faster and simpler

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34908/discussion-between-stano-and-alisamii)